# Pandas add new column in csv and save

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have code like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

for id1, id2 in zip(df.iterrows(),df.loc[1:].iterrows()):
    id1[1]['X_Next'] = id2[1]['X']
```

as you see, I need for each row to have next row's column value.
Iteration looks good, but I dunno how to save it bvack to csv file.
Can someone help me ? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df['X_Next'] = df['X'].shift(-1)
df.to_csv('file1.csv', index=False)
```